# Verify third party JWT with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm using external identity provider to authenticate users, created a SPA client (got `client_id` & `client_secret`), configured API with `audience` & `scope`, so once users authenticated they will get `access_token` (will be authorized) to access multiple custom micro-services (APIs).

When my custom API receives a request with a bearer Access Token (JWT) the first thing to do is to validate the token. In order to validate JWT I need to follow these steps:

1. Check that the JWT is well formed (Parse the JWT)
2. Check the signature. My external identity provider only supports RS256 via the JWKS (JSON Web Key Set) URL (https://{domain}/.well-known/jwks.json), so I can get my public key following this URL.
3. Validate the standard claims
4. Check the Application permissions (scopes)

There are a lot of packages/libraries (i.e. https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) to create JWT tokens but I can't find any to validate it using those steps above. Could anyone please help to find suitable Laravel/PHP package/library or move me to the right direction in order to achieve my goals (especially point #2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar in the past, I don't know if this may help but I'll give it a try. To use a public key, you should download it, put it somewhere on the disk (`storage/jwt/public.pem` for example) and then link it in the jwt config `config/jwt.php` with the ALGO (you can see supported algorithms [here](https://github.com/namshi/jose/tree/master/src/Namshi/JOSE/Signer/OpenSSL)

```php
    'keys' => [
        // ...    
        'public' => 'file://'.storage_path('jwt/public.pem'),
        // ...
    ],
    'algo' => 'RS256',
```

Then, you should have a custom Guard, let's call it JWTGuard:

```
<?php
namespace App\Guard;use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT;class JWTGuard implements Guard
{
    use GuardHelpers;       
    /**
     * @var JWT $jwt
     */
    protected JWT $jwt;       
    /**
     * @var Request $request
     */
    protected Request $request;    
    /**
     * JWTGuard constructor.
     * @param JWT $jwt
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function __construct(JWT $jwt, Request $request) {
        $this->jwt = $jwt;
        $this->request = $request;
    }       
    public function user() {
        if (! is_null($this->user)) {
            return $this->user;
        }           
        if ($this->jwt->setRequest($this->request)->getToken() && $this->jwt->check()) {
            $id = $this->jwt->payload()->get('sub');               
            $this->user = new User();
            $this->user->id = $id;
            // Set data from custom claims               
            return $this->user;
        }
        return null;
    }       
    public function validate(array $credentials = []) {    }
}
```

This should do all your logic of validation, I used a custom user implementation, the class signature was like:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {
    // custom implementation
}
```

Finally, you should register the guard in the AuthServiceProvider and in the auth config

```
public function boot()
{
  $this->registerPolicies();  
  $this->app['auth']->extend(
    'jwt-auth', 
    function ($app, $name, array $config) {
      $guard = new JWTGuard(
        $app['tymon.jwt'],
        $app['request']
      );      
      $app->refresh('request', $guard, 'setRequest');      
      return $guard;
    }
  );
}
```

then allow it in the config

```
<?php
return [
 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'jwt',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
 'guards' => [
        // ...
        'jwt' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt-auth',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ],
    ],
 // ...
];
```

You can then use it as a middleware like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:jwt')->get('/user', function() {
    return Auth::user();
}
```

Does this sound good to you?

Comment: Thanks, it will work and I've marked it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've used the Auth0 SDK for Laravel - https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/laravel/01-authorization. Nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't much help on this topic online for `PHP` and `Laravel`. After lots of trials and errors, I managed to validate the `JWT Token` using `firebase/php-jwt`. And putting the solution here so that in future anyone else can implement it easily.

**Please only use the accepted answer to implement the Laravel Auth via JWT Tokens. To validate the JWT tokens the correct approach is below.**

```
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\JWK;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log; 

//...

function validateJwtToken($jwt) {
    // split the jwt
    $tokenParts = explode('.', $jwt);
    $header = base64_decode($tokenParts[0]);
    $payload = json_decode(base64_decode($tokenParts[1]));

    // The below approach can be used to extract the key from the payload
    // You need to know which one exactly is the valid public key combination
    // For me it was on 0 index, but for better clarity, I've placed the key below
    // $jwk = (array)$payload->keys[0];

    $jwk = [
        'kty' => 'EC',
        'use' => 'sig',
        'crv' => 'P-256',
        'kid' => 'codilityhub-tu-es',
        'x'   => '9RZnkUM0uvAEMZfaF...',
        'y'   => 'lsKEv2uHKSFn2bkZV...',
        'alg' => 'ES256' //in your case the algo may be different
    ];

    try {
        // Verifies JWT token and return details otherwise raises SignatureInvalidException exception
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, JWK::parseKey($jwk));
        return true;
    } catch(\Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException $sigE) {
        Log::error("Error occured in verifyJwtToken details " . $sigE->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
//...
```

Some screenshots from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), from which you can identify if your token is valid or not. If it's valid there the above method does exactly same verification from within the code.

Below are the steps to verify the token in jwt.io.

**Step 1**

Choose the correct algo then copy and paste the `JWT Token` in jwt.io.

[image]

**Step 2**

Identify your correct key and copy the respective `JSON` for `Step 3`. Please remember to adjust the logic against `$jwk` variable in code for this key.

[image]

**Step 3**

Paste the `JSON` copied from `Step 2` in `verify signature` of jwt.io.

[image]